# Laravel 4 Won't update views content

Tags: php, laravel

For some reason, Laravel 4 won't update the content view that should be displayed in the browser.

For example, if I add one more item to the navigation menu, it is written on the view file, but not shown on the navigation list.

I have checked for any mispells, errors or anything related to this issue however I can't figure out if it's my mistake or it has to do with the cache.

What I've done:

1. Created the route for the url.
2. The related controller that will render the view.
3. Created the actual view with the content.
4. Added the item to the navigation file.

And I am sure that the view:

1. Extends with my layout
2. Included my content inside the @section and @stop'ed it.

And there are no errors displayed in the browser.

Also **I've checked the storage folder which contains the view's cache**, and I verified that the navigation file and the view file are phased correctly.

Looks like I need your advice guys.

Code as requested:

**The route**

```
Route::get('/account/profile', array(
'as' => 'account-profile',
'uses' => 'SettingsController@getProfileSettings'
));
```

**Navigation**

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-profile') }}">Edit profile</a></li>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getProfileSettings() {
    return View::make('account.profile');
}
```

**View**

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')
Edit your profile...

Not yet...
@stop
```

Comment: I could have helped you if you would have used a proper framework. If you want help from people that know a lot about anti-patterns, you should go to the Laravel community. I think people might want to see some code to help you here ;)

Answer (score 0):

First things I would do is:

1. Clear the view's cache folder.
2. check how you display the navigation, with @yield or @section, which should end with @show in the layout file.

If that didn't work maybe you could provide us with some code from the layout.

Comment: If I go to account/profile url, it displays it correctly. Just the navigation link won't appear.

Comment: Is there anything around the navigation link that control the visibility of it?